# Nagios NRPE: Command “my_command” not defined

Tags: linux, rhel6, nagios, nrpe

I have installed `Nagios® Core™ 3.5.1` and `NRPE v2.14` on my client which running `RHEL 6.3`

I have this error message on my Nagios

```
NRPE: Command 'check_mysql_connections' not defined
```

On my `nrpe.cfg` I already set up the `allowed_host, include_dir`:

```
allowed_hosts=xx.xx.xx.xx
dont_blame_nrpe=1
include_dir=/etc/nagios/services
```

my command is on `/etc/nagios/services/check_mysql_connections.cfg`

```
command[check_mysql_connections]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_mysql_all -K connections -H myHOST -u myUSERNAME -p myPASSWORD
```

On Nagios Server, I already set up the `nagios.cfg` file, and add the `commands-custom.cfg` on `/etc/nagios/objects` which contains like this:

```
define command {
command_name    check_mysql_connections
command_line    $USER1$/check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -c check_mysql_connections
}
```

and on `/etc/nagios/servers` I have add the `mysql.cfg`

```
## Define Host Group ##

define hostgroup {
hostgroup_name          mysql-databases
alias                   MySQL Databases
}

#######################
## Define Hosts ##

define host {
use             linux-server
host_name       bdgbnbpmydb02
alias           MySQL Database
address         xx.xx.xx.xx
hostgroups      mysql-databases
contact_groups  admins
check_command   check-host-alive
}

#######################
## Define Service ##

define service {
use                     generic-service
hostgroup_name          mysql-databases
service_description     MySQL Connections
check_command           check_mysql_connections
}
```

I already kill the `NRPE` process, removing `/var/run/nrpe.pid`, and start the NRPE process again. And also my NRPE is NOT running under xinet.d

When I try to execute the command locally on the remote host, it gives result. And when I try to execute from the nagios server using this command:

```
/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H xx.xx.xx.xx -c check_mysql_connections
```

it also gives result. I don't know what went wrong, because all of my other commands running normally.

**UPDATE & SOLVED**

after so many years, I recall how to solve this problem.

I need to edit the custom commands (on Nagios Server) `commands-custom.cfg` on `/etc/nagios/objects`, so it will be like this:

```
define command {
command_name         check_nrpe
command_line         $USER1$/check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -c $ARG1$ 
}
```

and under the "Define Service" it was like this:

```
## Define Service ##

define service {
use                     generic-service
hostgroup_name          mysql-databases
service_description     MySQL Connections
check_command           check_nrpe!check_mysql_connections
}
```

In summarize, I need to separate the command to check the service to be `check_nrpe` and call the custom commands using `check_nrpe!check_mysql_connections`

Reference:
https://support.nagios.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=33448

Comment: When you run the command manually from your Nagios server, are you root user or nagios user ?

Comment: It's an aside, but: `bdgbnbpmydb02`?  What a hostname!  See also http://serverfault.com/questions/479945/choosing-between-meaningful-and-meaningless-hostnames/479947#479947 .

Comment: Sorry to belabour the obvious, but - since you are kind enough to confirm you've restarted NRPE on the client - have you also restarted the NAGIOS server since your last edit to the config files?

Comment: I'd say "check SELinux", but you'd be getting different error messages if that were interfering with the plugin.  I assume that `nrpe` is running as the "nrpe" user; what does `ls -ldZ /etc/nagios/services /etc/nagios/services/check_mysql_connections.cfg` show?

Comment: How did you install NRPE? EPEL? Repoforge? Compiled?

Comment: @user2196728 : i try both of user and all of it gives result

Comment: @MadHatter: yes, definitely i already restart the nagios server

Comment: @asciiphil: i can't do it right at this moment, but i will give you the result once i can check that

Comment: @Keith: i compile it manually

Comment: Is there a reason you compile NRPE yourself?  Can you try the one in EPEL?  (Or repoforge, but I've had better experiences overall with EPEL; just don't use them both at the same time unless you're very careful.)

Comment: @asciiphil : this is the result: 
`-rw-r--r--. root root unconfined_u:object_r:nagios_etc_t:s0 /etc/nagios/services/check_mysql_connections.cfg`
 
the reason is, this server is not connected to internet connection, so I have to download the package manually, then compile it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start at one end and work your way back.

- You said "/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_mysql_all -K connections -H
  myHOST -u myUSERNAME -p myPASSWORD" works on the command line.
- You said that NRPE works on that server with other commands.
- You said that the command fails on the command line from the nagios
  server.

This suggests to me that the problem is in the definition on the NRPE server.  Is it possible that your obfuscated variables for myHOST, myUSERNAME, or myPASSWORD contain a character that is interpreted non-literally by NRPE?  (I'm assuming you've already checked for typos and duplicate definitions!)

Comment: All command both success from Nagios server and client. And no, all of myHOST,myUSERNAME, & myPASSWORD, do not contain strange character, all pure alphabetical characters.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry.  I must have misread.  :(  Check for duplicate command definitions on the Nagios server itself.  They may be hidden in /etc/nrpe.

Comment: I am sure there is no duplicate command definitions, since I've done installing nagios and nrpe, and I create it myself...maybe i just have to reinstall both nagios and nrpe??

Comment: They're working for the other plugins.  I assume you've already looked in /var/log/messages and /var/log/nagios3/nagios.log or the equivalent on your system...

Comment: your comment "This suggests to me that the problem is in the definition on the NRPE server" what bothers me at that time. So I try to re-define the commands, and it works. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps for adding a remote client disk check. These steps can be followed for the setup of mysql also.

**Client**

---

`vi /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg`

```
allowed_hosts=127.0.0.1,nagios_server_ip_here
dont_blame_nrpe=1
#checking root  partion
command[check_disk]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_disk -w 25% -c 20% -p /
```

**Server**

---

From the file `/usr/local/nagios/etc/resource.cfg` its given as `$USER1$=/usr/local/nagios/libexec`:

So, run the commands in terminal:

```
locate check_nrpe                              //find the location of check_nrpe
cp /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe /usr/local/nagios/libexec/
cd /usr/local/nagios/libexec/
chown nagios:nagios check_nrpe
```

Edit the file  `/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/commands.cfg`:

```
define command{
    command_name    check_disk
    command_line    $USER1$/check_nrpe -H '$HOSTADDRESS$' -t 30 -c check_disk
     }
```

Edit  `/usr/local/nagios/etc/servers/clients.cfg`:

```
define service {
    use                             generic-service
    host_name                       BI Server
    service_description             Disk
    check_command                   check_disk
    notifications_enabled           1
    }
```

**Restart services**

```
/etc/init.d/nagios restart                          //server side
/etc/init.d/nagios-nrpe-server restart             //client side
```

You can also check the commands in terminal as nagios user,

```
su - nagios
cd /usr/local/nagios/libexec/
./check_nrpe -H nagios_client_ip_here -t 30 -c check_mysql
./check_nrpe -H nagios_client_ip_here -t 30 -c check_disk
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I would suspect a permissions problem with that plugin. Be sure to run your manual tests as the nagios (or nrpe) user.

But in this case, it's claiming the NRPE command isn't even defined, so it's not even getting as far as running it...

Put the NRPE command def directly into nrpe.cfg, not in an included file. (And then restart NRPE.)

I recall having a similar problem (but with the NRPE from EPEL), a few years ago, where it wouldn't include another file in nrpe.cfg for some reason. I never did figure out why the include file didn't work, though.

Comment: i've done that, and it's just the same, i put command definition to `/etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg` and it got the same error

Comment: Then either you're looking at the wrong box, or the NRPE daemon isn't using that config file.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue for one of new checks I had implemented. Tried running check manually from Nagios Server

```
[foo@nagios.example.com]$ /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H db1.example.com -c check_mysql
NRPE: Command 'check_mysql' not defined
```

Turned out that Nagios NRPE Daemon on Nagios Client Server needed to restarted since it sources everything from nrpe.d into program memory

```
[foo@db1.example.com]$ sudo  /etc/init.d/nrpe restart
Shutting down Nagios NRPE daemon (nrpe):                   [  OK  ]
Starting Nagios NRPE daemon (nrpe):                        [  OK  ]
```

Ran the check again and was succeeding this time

```
[foo@nagios.example.com]$ /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H db1.example.com -c check_mysql
OK: MySQL is running fine.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptom. So maybe this will save someone else some time. My problem was that I was missing the .cfg extension on the files in the include directory.

My include dir was `include_dir=/etc/nagios/nrpe.d`

The machine is running Ubuntu 14.04 for reference, using NRPE v2.15

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue sometime ago, it turned out that someone already installed NRPE in the server (i didn't know), and when i tried to access it took the old NRPE version and configuration, the solution was look for the old NRPE and redirect the access...