# NRPE: Command 'check_ssh' not defined

Tags: linux, nagios, nrpe

We have a new Nagios Core server monitoring Linux hosts running NRPE plugins.  Most of them are working as expected, but the SSH Monitor is failing with "NRPE: Command 'check_ssh' not defined".  I can run check_ssh locally, but it's not working from the Nagios monitor.

[nagios_errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkity.png)

What am I doing wrong?  I can run check_ssh on the linix agent itself and it works.  Other plugins, like check_users, works when called from the nagios monitor with check_nrpe.

From the nagios monitor, calling check_nrpe on a linix agent:

[check_nrpe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1v81I.png)

Comment: is `check_ssh` included in `nrpe.cfg`?

Comment: there is your answer, as i mentioned you didn't defined `check_ssh` command in your `nrpe.cfg`, define it and it'll work ;-)

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/562845/nagios-nrpe-command-my-command-not-defined